# (React Native) Load local HTML file into WebView

Tags: webview, react-native

I try to load the local `.html` file into `WebView` in **React Native**:

```js
// load local .html file
const PolicyHTML = require('./Policy.html');

// PolicyHTML is just a number of `1`
console.log('PolicyHTML:', PolicyHTML);

// will cause an error: JSON value '1' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString
<WebView html={PolicyHTML} />
```

The `.html` file should be read as a string, not as a resource representative.

How can I load the `.html` file into `WebView` in React Native?

---

By the way, what is the type of those resource representatives from `require()`? Is it `number`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try it:

```
const PolicyHTML = require('./Policy.html');

<WebView
  source={PolicyHTML}
  style={{flex: 1}}
 />
```

Comment: It works in a development environment. In a release version follow this link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/505

Comment: @Fmussap, hm, but I use this solution on iOS release build, and it works

Comment: `react-native-webview` not work in expo web

Comment: not working in android

Answer (score 16):

I come across this post searching for loading static html.
If your html code is retrieved using, for example, an API, you can render WebView in this way:

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: html, baseUrl: '' }}
/>
```

Notice that `originWhitelist`is required as explained in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#source):

> Note that static html will require setting of originWhitelist for
>   example to ["*"].

Comment: Worth pointing out that the `baseUrl` part here is what I needed to fix mine, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7):

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <WebView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      source={require("./resources/index.html")}
    />
</View>
```

To make WebView, the parent has to has a dimension or flex:1. We could set the WebView to flex: 1 too so that it fills up the parent.

Answer (score 4):

With Expo tools and generally using Expo:

```
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { readAsStringAsync } from "expo-file-system";
import { useAssets } from "expo-asset";

export const MusicSheet = () => {
  const [index, indexLoadingError] = useAssets(
    require("../assets/musicsheetview/index.html")
  );

  const [html, setHtml] = useState("");

  if (index) {
    readAsStringAsync(index[0].localUri).then((data) => {
        setHtml(data);
    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        onLoad={() => {}}
        source={{ html }}
        onMessage={(event) => {}}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 100,
    display: "flex",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to serve **local assets** as well, then:

1. put all assets together with `index.html` into `android/app/src/main/assets/www` (You can copy them there with gradle task)
2. Then:

```js
  var uri = Platform.OS == "android" ?
    "file:///android_asset/www/index.html" :
    "./web/www/index.html"
  return <WebView source={{ uri }} />
```

** For iOS didn't tested, please add instruction, how assets should be stored

Comment: I get "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 2):

> If you're working with assets, project directories is different on the device's directory once the project is build and you can't simply reference them via string url.

### Expo

If using expo, you have to `require` every asset then use [`useAssets`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/) on the require to cache them to the local storage of the device.

`useAssets` will return an object that contains a `localUri`
(this is the uri of the image that has been cached)

you can then use the `localUri` and put it as the `src` of the image

```js
    import { useAssets } from 'expo-asset';
    /* . . . */
    const IndexHTML = require('./assets/index.html');
    const myImage = require('./assets/splash.png');

    // url link after image is cached to the device
    const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState('');

    const [image, imerr] = useAssets(myImage);
    const [html, error] = useAssets(IndexHTML);

    const webViewProps = {
        javaScriptEnabled: true,
        androidLayerType: 'hardware',
        originWhitelist: ['*'],
        allowFileAccess: true,
        domStorageEnabled: true,
        mixedContentMode: 'always',
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true,

        onLoad: () => {
            console.log(image[0].localUri);
            setImgSrc(image[0].localUri);
        },
        source: {
            html: '<img src="' + imgSrc + '"/>',
        },
    };

    return <WebView {...webViewProps} />
```

```js
    const webViewProps = {
        ...
        source: IndexHTML,
    };
```

**Note: for the expo apporach, files referenced in IndexHTML will not be found**

1. The trick is to turn your html into a `string literal` to utilize [template strings](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp).
2. Then you have to manually require each of those assets to concatenate `localUrl`
3. `require()` has limited types supported and you need to add a [`metro.config.js`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-non-image-resources) in your root folder.
4. it will give errors if you `require()` a `.js` file since it reads it as a module rather, the workaround approach would be to [bundle your assets](https://docs.expo.dev/archive/classic-updates/preloading-and-caching-assets/)

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.resolver.assetExts.push(
    // Adds support for asset file types
    'css', 'ppt', 'obj'
);

module.exports = config;
```

- Moreover, expo can hot reload changes done with the cached assets.

### React Native

If you have the `android` folder in your directory, navigate to

`android > app > build.gradle`

then add

```js
android {
    /* link assets to the local storage of device */
    sourceSets { 
        main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', '../../source/assets/'] } 
        //                      [do not touch,    'relative to your asset'] }
    }
    . . .
```

finally, the relative folder you linked in gradle can be accessed through
`file:///android_asset/`

for ex. `file:///android_asset/index.html` -> `/asset/index.html`

```js
return <WebView source={{uri: `file:///android_asset/index.html`}} />
```

- *For IOS, [here's how](https://yelotofu.com/react-native-load-local-static-site-inside-webview-2b93eb1c4225)*
- On the other hand, you have to rebuild vanilla react to see the changes in the assets.. *which takes about 20 minutes or so*

#### Alternative

A quick solution would be to integrate a [static server](https://github.com/birdofpreyru/react-native-static-server), but this is a recent fork of the `react-native-static-server` that only works in vanilla react native.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Add your *.html* file in your project.
- Write such lines of code in the file where you want to use WebView Component

  `const OurStoryHTML = require ('./OurStory.html')`
- `<WebView
   source={OurStoryHTML}
   style={{flex: 1, marginTop : 44}}
   />`

It may help you.