# html file is not linking/executing properly with react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am new to  developing react-native application in which i need to link html file.it gives blank output on my android emulator, even not any error. I just want to know how to link html file with react native. Basic code samples are given below..

i have gone through the this below link but it is not working in my scenario..
[(React Native) Load local HTML file into WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851296/react-native-load-local-html-file-into-webview)

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  WebView
} from 'react-native';

const DataHTML = require('./data.html');

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
     <View>
        <WebView
            source={DataHTML} 
            style={{flex: 1}}
            />                
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

data.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the WebView should appear. Try setting flex to 1 for both the View and the WebView or set explicit sizes.

```
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <WebView
       source={DataHTML}
       style={{flex: 1}}
    />
  </View>
```

Hope this helps !