# How to view the local HTML file in react native webivew for Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I have updated react-native version to 0.59 and I tried to view the local HTML file in webview. I am getting the view as 'page as web page not available'/ could not be loaded because of `net::ERR_ACESS_DENIED`

```
<WebView source={{uri:'file:///data/..../index.html'}}/>
```

Comment: Any example or sample of code will be helpful!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851296/react-native-load-local-html-file-into-webview#comment75325159_44140114

Comment: HTML file will not be within the app its present in the internal storage and also each and every time we need to load different html pages so 'require' is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Add your `index.html` to Android's `android/app/src/main/assets/` folder and then set

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' }}
/>
```

Comment: Its not a single HTML file each time it differs so we are storing the HTML files in internal storage