# How to run React JS build in React-Native Webview?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created complete offline ReactJS web application and I want to run it from android application from Web View using React-Native.

I followed the following procedure to do so: 
1. I created a compiled ReactJS web application got the `build` using the following command:

```
npm run build
```

2. Then I created react-native project and placed the `build` folder with following architecture
   [image: react-native with build folder]
3. I updated `App.js` with the following content:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, WebView} from 'react-native';
import {roscon} from "./build/index.html";

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{height: 300, width: 300,overflow:'hidden' }}>
          <WebView
            source={{uri: roscon}}
            scalesPageToFit={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            startInLoadingState={true}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

After running this code I expected it to run my ReactJS Web application, instead I got white screen.

Can you please tell what can be the causing issues and how i can make my ReactJS Web App run on react-native?

Note: I was able to run generated `build` folder using npm command

```
serve -s build
```

But I still can't figure out how to port it to react-native project as WebView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(React Native) Load local HTML file into WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851296/react-native-load-local-html-file-into-webview)

Comment: Tested, Didn't work..

Comment: You should be able to use the chrome dev-tools to inspect the webview in your react-native app. Can you try and show us any errors that might show up?

Comment: Hi, @JensV , I am replying late, But i got that issue solved. I also commented how i achieved that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After research and testing, I found a solution.
The main issue i found was the compiled `build` folder is rendered as `static html`. And it needed a `server` to serve pages.

So, I followed this [link](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths) for getting `build` project to get it up and running 
Then, integrating it with [nodejs Android Project Samples](https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile-samples) to get my `build` folder running in android as a Webview.

Note: I also tried `react-snapshot` and `react-snap` but they didn't gave satisfactory results.

Answer (score 1):

Try to require the html file correctly and pass it in to source prop in this way:

```
 <WebView
    source={require('./build/index.html')}
 />
```

Comment: Tried. It rendered the vanilla html code, So it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Install**

> **npm install react-native-react-bridge**

These are used to render React app in WebView
npm install react-dom react-native-webview

**Requirements**

1. react 16.8+
2. react-native 0.60+

**Usage**

1. Fix metro.config.js to use babelTransformer from this library.

> ```
>          module.exports = { 
>  transformer: {
>   babelTransformerPath: 
>  require.resolve('react-native-react- >. 
>    .bridge/lib/plugin'),
>        ...
>     },
>  };
> ```

2. Make entry file for React app. web.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
webViewRender,
emit,
useSubscribe,
} from "react-native-react-bridge/lib/web";

```
const Root = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  // useSubscribe hook receives message from React Native
  useSubscribe((message) => {
    if (message.type === "success") {
      setData(message.data);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{data}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // emit sends message to React Native
          //   type: event name
          //   data: some data which will be serialized by JSON.stringify
          emit({ type: "hello", data: 123 });
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

// This statement is detected by babelTransformer as an entry point
// All dependencies are resolved, compressed and stringified into one file
export default webViewRender(<Root />);
```

3. Use the entry file in your React Native app with WebView.

> 

```
import React from "react";
import WebView from "react-native-webview";
import { useBridge } from "react-native-react-bridge";
import webApp from "./WebApp";

const App = () => {
  // useBridge hook create props for WebView and handle communication
  // 1st argument is the source code of React app
  // 2nd argument is callback to receive message from React
  const { ref, source, onMessage, emit } = useBridge(webApp, (message) => {
    // emit sends message to React
    //   type: event name
    //   data: some data which will be serialized by JSON.stringify
    if (message.type === "hello" && message.data === 123) {
      emit({ type: "success", data: "succeeded!" });
    }
  });

  return (
    <WebView
      // ref, source and onMessage must be passed to react-native-webview
      ref={ref}
      source={source}
      onMessage={onMessage}
    />
  );
};
```