# React Native-Error:Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built-in components)or a class/function (for composite components)but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

I have this in my Comp:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component, } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, WebView } from 'react-native';




function AccurXVCS() {
   return(
       <View>

<WebView source={{html:"<html><body style='color:red'>Hello<br/>This is a test</body></html>"}}  />

       </View>
    
  );
}
```

export default AccurXVCS;

And this in my App Comp:

```
                import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
            import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
            import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
            import AccurX from './VideoCallingService/AccurXVCS';


            export default function App() {


              const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


              useEffect(() => {
                

              });




              return (




                
                <View style={styles.container}>
                  <AccurX></AccurX>
                </View>
              );
            }

            const styles = StyleSheet.create({
              container: {
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
              },
            });
```

why am i getting this error?

Comment: Webview is s separate package now, try installing it

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan: i added react-native-webview the error goes away but i get a black screen, the html has some text can you advise

Comment: maybe check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931187/1435722 you might have to provide the origin white list

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan, i think the reason is becuase im trying to run it in web. So i ran it on a android device version 7.0, im guessing react-native-webview does not work in android version 7?

Comment: I dont think that there is problem with the version, just check the library documentation they normally mention if there are any known issues